# how to view your accounts google play store money

Tags: google-play-store

I bought a nexus 7 in 2012 and it came with a $20.00 gift card. When I went to install apps from the app store, it asked me to sign into my google account. I signed into my gmail account and received the $20.00 for the play store. I purchased one or two items but I'm positive I still have a good $15.00 left. Where do I go to check how much google play store money I have left on my account? I went to wallet.google.com and it asked me to create a payment method, but I know for a fact that I still ahve a good $15.00 left on that gift card... Do the gift cards expire?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the TOS](http://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ca/about/card-terms.html), Google Play gift cards never expire.

You can view your balance by opening your [Google Wallet page](https://wallet.google.com/viewWallet) (you can also view your transaction history here to figure out where your money went) or by contacting Customer Care at 1-855-466-4438.

Comment: That Google Wallet page actually did show me when my credits expire. Thanks.

Comment: @MGOwen Interesting, I don't see when it expires anywhere.  Where do you see that information?

Answer (score 0):

Gift cards expire after a year of not being used, I think.

To check their value go to buy an app, and on payment methods, the card will be displayed with the value underneath. Then cancel out of buying the app.

Comment: This information is contrary to the answer provided by @Compro01 above.